# Sealing/insulating Overhang Sheathing

Tags: insulation, exterior, sealing

My house is located in NY and was built in the 1950s but has been recently remodeled. There are cold spots on the first floor directly above the cantilever and I wanted to check if it's possible to seal the exterior without removing existing structure. The cantilever is located above the basement foundation wall and about 12' long and extends 1.5' out from the house. I am can only access from the exterior as the interior has been completely finished.

Here is a picture of the exterior sheathing and underside of the overhang:
[image]

Would it help to install insulation foam board directly over the sheathing and seal the gaps with foam spray? Would that cause any moisture issues in the future?

edit to include additional details:

The interior rim joist is insulated with stone insulation and the interior walls is insulated with faced r19 fiberglass and covered with vapor barrier. There's no insulation between the floor joist.

Comment: Whether moisture is a concern depends on things you haven't told us. What's the insulation and interior vapor barrier situation?

Comment: The interior rim joist is insulated with stone insulation and the interior walls is insulated with faced r19 fiberglass and covered with vapor barrier. There's no insulation between the floor joist.

Comment: Don't tell us down here. Please take the [tour], then revise your question post with that information.